how to begin header and footer from the nth page in pdf rmarkdown
This is my YAML in R to generate a pdf document. 
\\clearpage forces everything after date (including table of contents) to move to the next page. 
Now header is shown in all pages except toc page. 
I want header to be also removed from the cover page. (ie. to have header from page 3 onward) 
I would appreciate any suggestions on this
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
      toc: true
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')` \\clearpage"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \fancyhead[LE,RO]{left header}
  - \fancyhead[RE,LO]{right header}
---

